# Quote markup in same article

Tags: html, blockquote

I'm working on a site that uses quotes to highlight sentences from the same article. See this example: [Polygon](http://www.polygon.com/2016/11/28/13661570/final-fantasy-15-review-xv-ff15-ps4-playstation-4-xbox-one-square-enix). Notice the "FINAL FANTASY 15 IS AMBITIOUS IN WAYS MOST GAMES NEVER TRY" and "FINAL FANTASY 15 PROVIDES AN EMOTIONALLY FULFILLING FINALE" sentences.

I throught the `<blockquote>` tag would be suited for this, but after reading the specification, I'm not sure it is:

> The blockquote element represents content that  is quoted from another source, optionally with a citation which must be within a footer or cite element, and optionally with in-line changes such as annotations and abbreviations.
>   Content inside a blockquote other than citations and in-line changes must be quoted from another source, whose address, if it has one, may be cited in the cite attribute. [emphasis mine]

The part I'm not sure about is "other source". The quote comes from the article it's in. So, technically, it's not an "other" source.

What's the correct markup for my use case?

Comment: I would say `<aside>`, but it's somewhat debatable.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've decided to stick with `<blockquote>`. Even tough the spec doesn't specifically say the quote can come from the same article, I do quote a source. I could indeed use `<aside>` for this, but the `<blockquote>` seems to suit this use case a little bit better.